# Are some bad practices within answers acceptable? Specifically SELECT *

Tags: discussion

[We know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc) that in production code `SELECT *` is bad.

However, I will often write `SELECT *` in my SQL answers when

- The OP failed to include their SQL (so I've got nothing to copy and paste)
- The OP's question is really answered with the `JOIN` or `WHERE`
- There's no syntax in my answer like `GROUP BY` that `SELECT *` can easily conflict with. [A]

Recently someone thought an answer of mine would be improved if I removed the `SELECT *`.
Obviously, I think it is acceptable to answer with `SELECT *` but I can't say why.

<sub>[A] I'm pretending that MySQL and its treatment of GROUP BY don't exist</sub>

Comment: I suspect that 'acceptable' depends on precisely *who* is currently looking at your answer, and whether that person has votes to spare. In the [tag:php] tag specifically I can think of one user that'll down-vote for the presence of (though possibly mitigated by explanation of/disclaimer for) a bad practice.

Comment: I like [Robert's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91558/are-some-bad-practices-within-answers-acceptable-specifically-select/91559#91559) but I think `SELECT ... FROM` also makes sense even to SQL newbies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just change it to

```
SELECT [your fields here] FROM
```

Or remind the OP to replace the asterisk with actual fields.

Comment: I think I'll start doing this since the intent is clear, isn't a bad practice, and I can still be lazy

Comment: -1 invalid column alias. Just kidding :)

Comment: I usually use `<columns>`

Comment: How about `SELECT yourcolumn1, yourcolumn2, etc FROM yourtable` ?

Answer (score 8):

Bad practices are OK as long as you note that they are bad practices. If you say something like "I'm doing this because it's shorter/unimportant/a placeholder", then it is clear to anyone reading your answer that they shouldn't copy that code directly into their finished product. However, if you don't have a disclaimer of some sort, an inexperienced programmer may believe that it is OK to use your code as-is, which could lead to future problems and them citing your answer as to why they thought it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I generally leave some kind of "please don't be as lazy as me" note at my own answers every time I use `SELECT *`, empty catch blocks and any other kind of dangerous stuff :D. This generally avoids both bad practices dissemination and "please don't do that" comments.